# Pass functions in a vm script context

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Let's say I have a library module that looks like this:

```
module.exports = {
    increment: function() {
         count++;
    }
}
```

And I'd like to use it in a dynamically generated script that looks like this:

```
(function() { lib.increment(); })();
```

by passing it in a sandbox:

```
var sandbox = {
    count: 1
    lib: require('./lib')
}
var script = new vm.Script('(function() { lib.increment() })();');
script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
```

The obvious problem I run into is that I on the one hand can't require "lib" because "count" is not defined in lib.js ; on the other hand if I define `var count` above the exports of the "lib.js" file, this new `count` variable will be affected instead of the one in the sandbox.

Here are the constraints that I would like to respect:

- Use vm and not a eval() nor a require() on a generated file
- Have "lib" defined in a external file
- No modification of the automatically generated script, so no use of `lib.increment.apply(context)` or similar

The only solutions I've found so far is to prepend the `lib` functions in the generated script as a string, or to define them directly on the `sandbox` object, which I find to be a less desirable option.

There doesn't seem to be any way of passing a context of variables on the `require` call.

Comment: Why not just have `exports` be a function that returns an object w/ get/set & increment methods?

Comment: Or you can have the exports be a function which takes a context. Then you can do `require('./lib')({ count: 1 })` and it will return an object with the `increment` function.

Comment: @MikeC See, that's why you should never be afraid to ask, that's actually a quite good suggestion!

Comment: Is `global.count++` what you want to do?

Comment: @Bergi what do you mean with "global"? I need to change the one passed as a context in the sandbox.

Comment: @MikeC I'll probably go with your idea, you may post an answer so I can accept it ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One way of accomplishing this is have your `lib` module be a function that takes in a context then returns the correct interface.

lib.js

```
module.exports = function(context) {
  var count = context.count;
  return {
    increment: function() {
      count++;
    }
  };
};
```

main.js

```
var sandbox = {
  count: 1
};
sandbox.lib = require('./lib')(sandbox);
var script = new vm.Script('(function() { lib.increment() })();');
script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
```