# Passing context from a vm.Script to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, v8

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38316876/pass-functions-in-a-vm-script-context),

I'm running a vm.Script with a custom context, which provides a way to run another vm.Script.

I would like to pass the context of the first vm.Script to the second vm.Script.

However, when I test the following:

```
var util = require('util');
var vm = require('vm');

var code1 = 'debug(this);'
    + '(function(val) {'
    + '  this.test = 2;'
    + '  lib.increment();'
    + '  lib.subcall(this);'
    + '})();'

var code2 = 'debug(this);';


var context = {
    count: 1,
    subcall: function(scope) {
        console.log(util.inspect(scope));
        var script = new vm.Script(code2);
        script.runInNewContext(scope);
    }
};

var sandbox = {
    context: context,
    lib: require('./lib')(context),
    debug: function(message) { console.log(util.inspect(message)); }
}

var script = new vm.Script(code1);
script.runInNewContext(sandbox);
```

With `lib` module containing:

```
module.exports = function(context) {
    return {
        increment: function() {
            context.count++;
        },
        subcall: function(scope) {
            context.subcall(scope);
        }
    };
};
```

I get a ReferenceError *(debug is not defined)* inside the `code2` vm.Script.

The output is:

```
// debug(this) inside code1
{ context: { count: 1, subcall: [Function] },
  lib: { set: [Function], increment: [Function], subcall: [Function] },
  debug: [Function] }
// console.log inside subcall
{ test: 2,
  context: { count: 2, subcall: [Function] },
  lib: { set: [Function], increment: [Function], subcall: [Function] },
  debug: [Function] }
```

Basically I was hoping to run the second code with the same context, to which the `test` field assigned in the first code would be added.

Why is it not the case?

Comment: Where do you call `code2`?

Comment: @user835611 in `subcall`. I've also realized this code has a different result on Windows and *nix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you set

`this.debug = debug;`

in line 6, i.e., inside the anonymous function in `code1`, you have access to `debug()` inside the second sandbox.

It seems to me like `debug()` should be available in `code2`. Might be good to add your case to this issue [node#6283](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/6283).